# ToastNotification in UWP not working across devices

Tags: notifications, win-universal-app

I am developing an Universal Windows App using Mobile App as backend as well as SQLLite for offline sync. My app needs to show reminders to the users and I am using ToastNotification for that. So if a user insert a data for a reminder, she should get notification at that time. This works fine.

The problem is that, when a user has created a reminder in mobile phone, then she gets notification only on phone and not on her windows 10 laptop. and if she creates a reminder on her windows 10 laptop, then she doesnt get the notification on her phone.

The list of reminders, however is in sync and user can see same list from both the devices, however she gets notifications only for the ones that she created from that device.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The reminders are local notification, in order to make them available for other device, you can sync them over backend. Then send push notification to other devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah I thought so but I dont want to use push notifications as then user will have to have internet access to get those notifications. 
I was hoping to get the list of scheduled notifications for that device using ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().GetScheduledToastNotifications() and then check if a reminder for that item exist or not, if not then add it in scheduled notification.
However, the problem is that GetScheduledToastNotification is not returning the scheduled notifications consistently. at times it returns 0, at times it returns more :S